# CSS: how to transform a navigation into a hamburger menu for mobile devices

Tags: css

I'm relatively new to modern CSS so I would like to ask you for any advice regarding how to proceed if I want to transform a multi level navigation menu into a hamburger menu for mobile devices (preferably without JS involved).
What I have so far looks good on desktop & tablet screen, but for a mobile screen I'd like to have a hamburger menu (either on left or right side of the screen) where all items in original menu would be available.

CSS code for desktop & tablet screens:

```
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to use media queries to detect the small width and then apply different styles to create what you want.

Comment: Yes, I already have media queries for various displays involved, but I'm stuck on how to transform that menu into hamburger menu for mobiles only..

Comment: Media queries need to be used to detect when the screen size is below 768px (`@media screen and (max-width:767px) { // your code // }`). and then you'll have to use JavaScript / jQuery to make the movile navigation actually appear when the user clicks on the hamburger.

Comment: Ideally you need to provide us with your full code, this way we'll be able to help you more with the JS that needs to be included for your issue to be fixed.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 - so it is temporarily located here: http://www.egyptica.sk/test/index1.php and CSS file is located on http://www.egyptica.sk/test/styles/main-styles.css" .

Comment: There are pure css solutions for a hamburger menu that you can adjust to your media query css. Like here https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP and here https://codepen.io/jlnljn/pen/LkXoBb i.e.

Comment: @Olafant Thank you, that 1st link is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated :)

Comment: @JanaR You're welcome. I like that you don't want to use jQuery for things that you can achieve with css.

Comment: @Olafant : an edit to my previous reply: that 1st link is almost what I was looking for, however that makes navigation to be hamburger on all displays while I need it as hamburger only on mobile screens (not on desktop)..

Comment: As I said - you need to adjust it for your needs. Make the normal menu only visible on big screens and the hamburger only visible on small screens. Or just search for responsive menu css only. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Responsive-Navigation-jQuery-menuBreaker.html

you can use this JQ plugin on the go to solve your issue effectively, plus you will not have to change your html structure extensively

Comment: @Vabhav Chauhan - thank you for suggestion, but I would like to avoid either JS or JQery if possible.

Comment: checkbox method is a fine way to go ahead with then if ur using only css.
https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP
take this reference..
also using js in the current era of reactive frameworks will not make your application look slower

Answer (score 0):

So I found what fits the best (so far): https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/ Anyways, all suggestions are much appreciated :)